# Need to sort value from web request response

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I need to sort specific value of BuildName: from web request response.

How can I store a particular response in a variable?

Trying with following command

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://s3.amazonaws.com/$url/env.js | select-object Content
```

I am getting the following response. I need to sort the values from there

Response will be like this

window.env = {
// Hardcode environment variables in here but tokenize customer specific ones with #{}#
BuildName: 'AppClient-develop-0716.4'
GRAPH_QL_HOST: 'https://xyz.google.com/graphql'
};

From her need to get value of BuildName:

Comment: What do you need to sort? There's only one line in `{...}`?

Comment: I need to get value of GRAPH_QL_HOST: into variable

Will be adding one more field like build version which will be my version for app ... That i want to get from here and store in DB

If i can get value of GRAPH_QL_HOST: similarly i can get for buildVersion

Comment: What is the returned content type? Is it JSON?

Comment: No not json i tried to convert to json but getting issue...
checked type 

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                  
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat but following might get you started: 
`(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://s3.amazonaws.com/$url/env.js).Content -split "`r`n" | Select-String "\w+:" | % { ($_ -split ": '")[1]}`

Comment: @SaurabhPatil, it is a custom object because you are using `Select-Object`, which converts it to `PsCustomObject` type. Just use `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://s3.amazonaws.com/$url/env.js).Content | ConvertFrom-Json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the content to individual strings and parse those to get the individual values.

**Example**

```
# $Content = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://s3.amazonaws.com/$url/env.js).Content
$Content = @'
window.env = { 
  // Hardcode environment variables in here but tokenize customer specific ones with #{}# 
  BuildName: 'AppClient-develop-0716.4' 
  GRAPH_QL_HOST: 'xyz.google.com/graphql' 
 };
'@ 

$Content -split "`r`n" | Select-String "\w+:" | % { ($_ -split ": ")[1]}
```

Comment: Thanks Lieven, got exact value of BuildName:  as  AppClient-develop-0716.4
 by adding as below this that worked for me which resolved my issue 


`$Content -split "`r`n" | Select-String "BuildName:" | % { ($_ -split "'")[1]}`